# A platform is kept on a frictionless surface and a man of the same mass is standing on one end. Can he ever reach the other end?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

We can take two cases:

1. There is no friction between the man and the platform: When the man pushes the platform backward, it should push him forward by Newton's third law. Since the mass of both the man and the platform are equal, their accelerations should also be equal by Newton's second law. But since the platform itself is moving and the man is on the platform, will he move at all?
2. There is friction between the man and the platform: It should be similar to the above case, except friction will tend to oppose relative motion between the man and the plank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. There is no friction between the man and the platform: When the man
>    pushes the platform backward, it should push him forward by Newton's
>    third law.

As already noted in the other answers, without friction there is no force to push the platform backwards, and therefore no reaction force to push the man forwards per Newton's 3rd law. The only action reaction forces are in the vertical direction.

> 2. There is friction between the man and the platform: It should be
>    similar to the above case, except friction will tend to oppose
>    relative motion between the man and the platform (plank).

Static friction will prevent the man from slipping on the platform, as long as the maximum possible static friction force ($\mu_{s}mg$) between the man and platform is not exceeded.

But static friction does not prevent the man from moving relative to the platform. It causes it. Just as static friction at the drive wheels of a car causes a car to push backwards on the ground and the ground to push forwards on the car causing it to accelerate forward. Static friction thus allows the man to traverse the platform and reach the other end. If there were no static friction, the man would not be able to move horizontally and reach the end of the platform. Such motion would necessitate the existence of some other external horizontal force.

It should be noted that since there is no friction on the surface below the platform and the platform, there is no net external horizontal force acting on the combination of the man and platform. Consequently, there will be no horizontal acceleration of the center of mass of the man+platform relative to the ground though the man and platform individually accelerate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When the wheels of a car push the ground backward, the ground pushes it forward by Newton's third law. What is the role of friction here, doesn't friction oppose relative motion between two objects?

If the car pushes the floor with a force F, the floor should push it forward with F, but if this is related to static friction, like you said, the maximum force the floor can apply is $\mu_s N$.

Comment: Static friction prevents slipping from happening. Kinetic friction opposes slipping once slipping occurs

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict.html

Answer (score 1):

1 - If there is no friction between the man and the platform, the man can't push the platform. Unless friction is developed or the platform gets a handle, neither the man nor the platform move.

2 - If there is friction between the man and the platform, when the man tries to walk on the platform the platform moves in the opposite direction. Since man and platform have the same mass both will move at the same velocity. If the man is moving at speed v relative to the platform, an observer in an inertial frame outside the platform (that in the beginning saw the man and the platform at rest) will see the man and the platform moving at velocity v/2 in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no friction he as no possibility of "pushing". He could jump upward and move part of his body forward. With friction he can push, so the platform goes one way and he the other. So he does move relative to the platform but not relative to ground.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no friction, the man can move with respect to the platform using air: driving air with his arms or blowing out air. If there is no air, the man has a more pressing problem:-)